# installing emacs with x-toolkit

Tags: fedora, xorg, software-installation, emacs

I am installing Emacs 24.5.0, and I want to install it with X. I am on Fedora. the configuration script cannot find any x-toolkit. How do I find out which one is good for me, and in which folder do I find it?

Somewhere I have read that the x-toolkit for fedora should be gtk. How can I check if and where this library is installed?

Answer (score 0):

`rpm -q gtk3-devel`, at the most basic level.

But, installing that is not necessarily going to pull in everything you need. You can short-cut this by installing the GNOME Software Development group. (Even if you are not doing GNOME development, this happens to be a group which contains gtk3-devel and many related packages.)

Do this:

```
sudo yum groupinstall gnome-software-development
```

And, actually, you'll probably want to make sure X Software Development is there too, as well as all of the basic C development tools. So:

```
sudo yum groupinstall gnome-software-development x-software-development c-development-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a problem building xpm-3.4k where the process could not find -lXt. We did the following on CentOS 7: `yum install *Xt*`.

Prior to that we did `yum install xorg*dev*` to get the other X development builds.

We tried to build from the X source, but that proved to be way too time consuming. So, it is great that  the good people at CentOS have the development RPMS.

Comment: So did you install the RPMS or from source?

Comment: We installed the RPMs using 'yum'. We will dissemble the RPMs later. No a priority right now as the 'devel' is working.